# Even change href with id

Tags: jquery, href

How to automatically change href when have id.
I have a tab:

```
<a href="../Main/Profile.aspx" id="btnChangeProflie" class="main-User">Account</a>
```

When my website open will auto change `href="..Page/Main/Profile.aspx"`. I try some jquery but don't change.
Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - you want to change the href to what...? Why changing it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to prepend `Page` to href when anchor element have `id`.

```
$("a[id]").each(function( index, element ){
  var newHref = "..Page" + $(this).attr("href").replace('..', ''); 
  $(this).attr("href", newHref);
});
```

This will select all anchor elements which have `id` attribute.
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b978km32/)